# is there anyway to do a replace in SQL based on starting and ending characters

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to run an update on a field to replace

```
<div>[Any text]</div>
```

to

```
 Any text
```

So anywhere it sees a pattern of `<div>...</div>` surrounding text, it removes these outer characters

Is this possible to do in SQL Server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx)

```
update t set c = replace(replace(c, '<div>', ''), '</div>', '');
```

Comment: can you clarify here . . where is the indication on which column to use this replace on ??

Comment: `c` is the column name `t` is the table

Comment: This wouldn't account for only removing tags with matching start and end, but maybe it's all you need?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use MySQL %like statements to find strings with are similar, or include specific parts of text : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html